# I need to find how much light is in a point in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a video game in unity. In this video game, we have a thing named Mental Health. This decreases by 1 point per x seconds. The illumination of the surroundings of the player determines the seconds.

So, the problem is simple, I need to know how much light is in the player game object (all the time, like, in the Update method). I've tried using Light Probe groups, recommended by ChatGPT, but after reading the official documentation and failing repeatedly, I don't think it's the answer.

Comment: Don't ask ChatGPT for stuff like this. It hasn't magically unlocked the secret knowledge, it just regurgitates basic phrases from Google search results in the hopes that it sounds enough like a programmer to convince you that it is smart. You have a light test problem that is often encountered in stealth games. The solution is always the same. You make a list of all light sources. You raycast from the player to the light. If there are no obstacles found you are lit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a go myself, couldn't help it!

Let me know if I understood properly, and this is what you were after:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Light[] lights;
    public float maxDistance = 10.0f;
    public float healthDecreaseSpeed = 1.0f;
    public float minimumHealth = 0.0f;
    public float maximumHealth = 100.0f;
    private float currentHealth;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maximumHealth;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float distanceSum = 0.0f;

        // Loop through all the lights in the array
        foreach (Light light in lights)
        {
            // Get the distance from the player to the current light
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, light.transform.position);

            // Clamp the distance to a maximum of maxDistance
            distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance, 0.0f, maxDistance);

            // Add the clamped distance to the total distance sum
            distanceSum += distance;
        }

        // Calculate the average distance from the player to all the lights
        float averageDistance = distanceSum / lights.Length;

        // Calculate the health decrease speed based on the average distance
        float decreaseSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(0.0f, healthDecreaseSpeed, averageDistance / maxDistance);

        // Decrease the current health based on the decrease speed and the time since the last frame
        currentHealth -= decreaseSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Clamp the current health to the minimum and maximum values
        currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth, minimumHealth, maximumHealth);

        // Output the current health to the console
        Debug.Log("Current Health: " + currentHealth);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I need to restructure the code a little because it wasn't the whole thing in the question, but this will be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to calculate the player's proximity to light sources to determine how much the player's Mental Health should decrease. This would be easier than trying to measure light values, and provides some advantages (such as being able to detect baked and real-time lights).

Firstly, you can determine what counts as a "light source". Is it any game object with a light component? Are there specific types of lights that you're interested in? This will help you identify what objects you need to check the player's proximity to.

Decide how you want to measure proximity. Do you want to use distance in 3D space, or something else? Depending on your game's design, you might also want to consider things like line-of-sight or occlusion‍♀️

Once you've identified the relevant game objects and how you want to measure proximity, you can write the code to calculate the player's proximity to each light source One way to do this is to use the Vector3.Distance method in Unity to find the distance between the player's position and the position of each light source.

Once you have the distances, you can use them to determine how much the player's health should decrease. You mentioned that the health decrease depends on the number of lights in proximity and the amount of light, so could also check the range/intensity of the light, and then decide how to combine the distances from each light source and their range/intensity into a single value that determines x.

I hope this helps!